# Do the different armament slot have different damage potential in Elden Ring?

Tags: elden-ring

On the Level Up menu, leveling up Strength seems to affect only R. Armament Slot 1 and 3...? What exactly is going on here and why do the different armament slots have different values? When I view the in-game help, it just says "Attack power of the armament equipped in right hand slot X". However, when I checked my R. Slot 2, the bow I have there is around 80 only so nowhere near the 200 shown here.

And why does it only affect slot 1 and 3 and not 2?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different weapons scale with different statistics. The bow you currently have in slot 2 does not scale with strength at all - it derives all of its attack power from other stats (probably Dexterity, but this varies by specific weapon).

If you look at your various weapons, you’ll see a list of statistics, each with a letter grade (A,B,C, etc.) - these grades represent a multiplier that determines how much that weapon bennefits from that statistic. So, for example, a weapon with A strength scaling, will gain more attack power per point of strength than a weapon with C strength scaling.

These scaling ratios also will improve and change as the weapon increases in level.

Comment: I see, thanks !